# Fail to load bundle when impor third library

Tags: react-native

I use `create-react-native-app` to create a new project and type `npm run eject` make the app become pure react-native app.

Then my step is:

1.`npm install --save react-native-elements`

2.`react-native link react-native-vector-icons`

But when i just add this code

`import { Button } from 'react-native-elements';` in my `App.js`

Run it that will show the error like this:
[image]

I check my terminal the error prints:

```
error: bundling failed: Error: While trying to resolve module `react-native-elements` from file `/Users/huaweb/ReactNativeProject/Huaweb2/App.js`, the package `/Users/huaweb/ReactNativeProject/Huaweb2/node_modules/react-native-elements/package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`/Users/huaweb/ReactNativeProject/Huaweb2/node_modules/react-native-elements/src/index.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:
```

Why i can't import my library ? I can't figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try killing any metro bundler running and try restarting it again ?

Comment: run this command to check if their is any running bundler process
`ps aux | grep react-native` and kill it using `kill -9 <pid>`
pid: indicates process id here.
Above will work on linux based system only, check for alternate commands if you are on Windows.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't kill any metro bundle and i have try restart the project again , it still shows the error if i just import `import { Button } from 'react-native-elements';`.
You post the type command is still working on mac ?

Comment: Yes, it should work on mac and should return list of processes if any.

Comment: Also could you confirm if you have followed the steps mentioned here :
https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/0.19.0/getting_started.html#installation ?

Comment: I try `ps aux | grep react-native` and see two informations:
`huaweb           28778   0.7  0.0  4267752    816 s003  S+    5:36下午   0:00.00 grep react-native.  

huaweb           28634   0.0  0.0  4271404    884 s001  S+    5:28下午   0:00.01 bash /Users/huaweb/ReactNativeProject/Huaweb3/node_modules/react-native/scripts/launchPackager.command
`
If i want to type `kill -9 <pid>`. What is the pid ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: And yes, i'm sure i follow the official step, i use it for a long time before. This time I create the React Native project from another Mac then i stuck in this issue...

Comment: pid is the process id which you have to pass if you intend to kill it using kill command. From what I can see, I assume it to be `28778` for the first process and `28634`. I think its the 2nd process which you might want to kill i.e. the metro bundler process.

Comment: @sghosh968 I find my problem is i have to type `npm install --save react-native-vector-icons` not really `react-native link react-native-vector-icons`. I solve my issue now. Thanks for your help truly.